# C++ compile-time non-intrusive struct to tuple (or any another) class conversion

Tags: c++, serialization, reflection

**Prerequisites:**
I have no access to boost.
Im have third-party C header, what describes structs, like

```
typedef struct
{
   int int_value;
   char char_value;
   bool bool_value;
}
example_struct_t;
```

I cant make any changes in it.

**Target:**
I need to serialize data from this structs in custom text format.

I have planned, to make by-type serializers, like `SerializerBase, SerializerINT::SerializerBase`, `SerializerCHAR::SerializerBase` and etc.

And use it in some template class, (pseudocode):

```
Serializer<example_struct_t = T>
{
   foreach_field_in<T> is field
   {
      if(field.type == typeof(int))
      {
         AddToResult(SerializerINT::Serialize(field.value));
      }
   }
}
```

Or something less "templated" (pseudocode):

```
class SerializationSequence<example_struct_t = T>
{
   std::vector<SerializerBase> sequence;

   SerializationSequence()
   {
       sequence = GenerateMethodsSequenceForThisStruct<T>(); // Compile time
   }
}
```

Does C++ has any way to parse this structs in compile time and making something, like
`std::tuple<int,char,bool>`?

Comment: Are you not allowed to use boost, or would a standalone header be allowed? Because magic_get aka boost.pfr is a 1 header library, and does exactly that: https://github.com/apolukhin/magic_get

Comment: Yes, im able to use this header. But at my first attempt, im havent  found way to solve my problem with that. Pls, make it as answer, cause this hase standalone non-boost version.  https://github.com/apolukhin/pfr_non_boost. Im still trying to understand first answer by @Yakk_-_Adam_Nevraumont and later try PFR again. My competence is on the bleeding edge with this two...

Comment: AFAIK, the lower part of Yakks answer describes the basic idea behind boost.pfr/magic_get.

Answer (score 1):

C++ reflection proposal does this easy.  It isn't in C++ yet.

There are various ways you can get at C++ parse trees.  It is pretty extreme and involves hacking or using a custom compiler.

Finally, there are some hacks involving detecting airity of brace construction and unpacking with `[]`s.  This might be the most practical.

The basic idea is you can test, in an immeditate context, if `T{a0, a1, a2}` is legal.  You make a type that has a "universal" `template<class T>operator T()`, and find the largest count of those you can make an instance of your type from using `{}`s.

Then you unpack via

```
auto&& [b0, b1, b2] = t;
return std::make_tuple(b0,b1,b2);
```

and extract the types from the resulting tuple, with a custom ("hand" written) version for each count.

It requires a bunch of code generation, has a max airity it handles, it only handles POD types well (with some extensions).  But that technique is the closest you can get in current C++.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/utilForever/1a058050b8af3ef46b58bcfa01d5375d) is someone using this approach.  I have no idea if they did it well, the license they used, etc; it is just an example of someone else doing this technique.

Answer (score 0):

The OP wrote that using boost is not possible, but then noted that the inclusion of a single header is possible.
magic_get aka boost.pfr is a 1 header library, and should do exactly what the OP wants: turning a simple struct into a tuple. See [github.com/apolukhin/magic_get](https://github.com/apolukhin/magic_get)